# How can I make lazy this Depth First Search funktion in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In the resource https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMMc4VsIacU is give an iterative algorithm for DFS which I mostly transferred to Haskell, which returns the visited ordering for later visiting, which is equivalent to the normal visitor function. This produces the following performance problem:
1. I have to await to get the entire visitor order to actually make the visits
This problem could be solved with some function design of which are not aware or by lazyfing the operation which I don't know how to do.

Thus how Can I lazify the following Haskell function such that I can get the visitor list only computing the search part for nodes that are in the marked list

```hs
dfs_prae :: Eq e => Graph e -> e -> [e]
dfs_prae graph jetzige = innerDfs jetzige []
    where
        innerDfs :: e -> [e] -> [e]
        innerDfs jetzige jetzigeGemarkte = schleife [jetzige] jetzigeGemarkte []
        
        schleife :: [e] -> [e] -> [e] -> [e]
        schleife []                  _       visited = visited
        schleife xs gemarkt visited = schleife jetzigStack jetzigGemarkt jetzigVisited
            where
                jetzigVisited = if not (jetzige `elem` visited) then visited ++ [jetzige] else visited
                jetzigStack = if not (jetzige `elem` gemarkt) then foldr (:) stackTail wandernbarNachbaren else stackTail
                jetzigGemarkt = jetzige:gemarkt
                wandernbarNachbaren =  nachbarschaftBekommen jetzige jetzigGemarkt
                jetzige = head xs
                stackTail = tail xs

        nachbarschaftBekommen :: e -> [e] -> [e]
        nachbarschaftBekommen jetzige marked = filter (not . (\x -> elem x marked)) (nachbaren graph jetzige)
```

Comment: Does this compile, I haven't tried it, but from a cursory glance, I'd expect `[jetzige:stackTail]` was meant to be `(jetzige:stackTail)`

Comment: @Joe you were right I just checked in my haskell instance

Comment: The [fgl paper](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/old/fgl0103.pdf) discusses what must be done to create an idiomatic, lazy depth-first search, so that may be useful for you.

Comment: I don't understand this question. "it must be a 'generator' which visitor function is only to get the reverse of the marked elements" -- What does "it" refer to? What is a "visitor function"? What is an "element"? What is a "marked element"? "get the visitor list only computing the search part for nodes that are in the marked list" -- What is a "visitor list"? What is a "search part"? `dfs_prae :: Eq e => Graph e -> e -> [e]` -- What is `Graph`?

Comment: @DanielWagner What happened is that in the start it was in some way, with an extra problem, but decided in that it was unnecessary complexity and forgot to update that text

Comment: Is it possible to "translate" the code to English, I'm not very proficient in German.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem nachbarschaftBekommen is getNeighborhood, jetzige is current, gemarkt is marked, schleife is loop, wandernNachbaren is walkableNeighbors

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem lucky you, for me as a German it's complete torture to read this code...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to make at least the following change:

```
- schleife xs gemarkt visited = schleife jetzigStack       gemarkt       visited
+ schleife xs gemarkt visited = schleife jetzigStack jetzigGemarkt jetzigVisited
```

It is possible there are other bugs or bad behaviors.